# How to scale the byte[] data on android Camera's onPreviewFrame to a lower resolution

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediacodec

Android camera have a onPreviewFrame call back which gives you back a frame as byte[] data.

I have set up my Camera to return data (in NV21 format) byte[] data at 1280 x 720.

**What I wanted to do:**

I would like to keep some of the frames at 1280 x 720 resolution(to jpeg).

And generate a mp4 elementary stream at a lower resolution(something like 720 x 480).

**Problem**

MediaCodec would error out if the MediaFormat.Key_Width and MediaFormat.Key_Height is not equal to the onPreviewFrame's width and height.

I would like to know if its possible to scale my byte[] data(NV21) from 1280 x 720 to something lower like 720 x 480 resolution and then feed it to the encoder?

If it is possible, what are the steps for converting a byte[] data of NV21 at 1280 x 720 resolution to a lower resolution.

thanks for reading, and would appreciate any suggestions or helps.

Comment: If you use the Surface preview output, you can render it at whatever resolution you want -- and the GPU does all the work.  You can't get at the pixels directly in this mode, so to save a frame you'd need to render it a second time to a full-sized pbuffer and read it back from that.  See http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#CameraToMpegTest for an example.

Comment: ...and http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#ExtractMpegFramesTest for an example of saving frames as PNGs at an arbitrary resolution.

Comment: ...and https://github.com/google/grafika, an Android app that includes an example of showing camera preview on-screen while simultaneously recording it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Have a look at library https://code.google.com/p/libyuv/. It can scale yuv images, convert between different color formats also it has SIMD optimisations (it is pretty fast).